Given a binomial coefficient and either a row or column index, is it better to approximate the other, or find its limiting value?
Suppose you want to express Pascal's triangle as a table, with $n=m+p$ being the diagonal in terms of rows $m$ and columns $p$, and the binomial coefficient is given by:
$$\binom{m+p}{p}=\frac{(m+p)!}{m!p!}$$
With either $m$ or $p$ and some number $N$, which may or may not be a binomial coefficient, you can retrieve the row or column by using the following recurrence formulas:
$$m:=r_1=\left [\frac{2(N-1)+{r_0}^2}{2r_0+3} \right] \iff r_{n+1}=r_n$$
This is for the triangular numbers (i.e. $p =2$) and it's read: "$m$ is defined by a number equal to that expression until the last result is equal to the previous one. You can set $r_0=0$ to begin the approximation, when $m=0$ is the exact result of $N=1$ in any column $p$. The brackets correspond to the round function, and rounding means that, when you're given a number that is not a binomial coefficient, you find the nearest one to the former.
Here's a few more formulas for $p=3,4$.
$$m:=r_1=\left [\frac{6(N-1)+6{r_0}^2+2{r_0}^3}{3{r_0}^2+12r_0+11} \right] \iff r_{n+1}=r_n$$
$$m:=r_1=\left [\frac{24(N-1)+35{r_0}^2+20{r_0}^3+3{r_0}^4}{4{r_0}^3+30{r_0}^2+70r_0+50} \right] \iff r_{n+1}=r_n$$
These formulas are the result of considering polynomials in terms of $m$, translating them to the right by evaluating $m+r$, and performing a truncation of any terms whose degree in $m$ is higher than 1 so that $m$ is linear. Then, it's only a matter of using a numerical method to find the target number through approximation, since the original expression was cut off. Their generalization is as follows:
$$m:=r_1=\left [\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} (p-i)(N-1)+\sum_{i=0}^{p-2} (p-1-i){r_0}^{p-i} \times C_{i,p}}{\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} (p-i){r_0}^{p-1-i} \times C_{i,p}} \right] \iff r_{n+1}=r_n$$
where there is a coefficient whose value is given by:
$$C_{i,p} = \sum_{0 \le j_0 \lt ... \lt j_{i-1} \le p-1} \prod_{k=0}^{i-1} (p-j_k)$$
This is an expression for the sum of all distinct products using $j_k$ within that interval.

The question is: is it better to round the result that I'm trying to get to evaluate it in the following recursive step until it's equal, or should I consider the limiting value of this expression without rounding, so that I'm not potentially missing anything? On one hand, rounding makes it easier to use the calculator to help a handwritten computation, while on the other it may be more formal to express the result as a limiting value. I'm sorry for the context being way too long.
